# jsfiddle not finding github repo

Tags: github, jsfiddle

I'm trying to change this fiddle to a github fiddle :
[jsfiddle.net/h4kbn3pv/6/](https://jsfiddle.net/h4kbn3pv/6/).

```html
<h1>coinbase balance</h1>
<button type="button" onClick="watchBalance();">watch balance</button>
<div></div> <div id="coinbase"></div>
<div id="original"></div>
<div id="current"></div>
<div id="diff"></div>
```

So I added it to my repo [github.com/Jorropo/web3/tree/fixing-2089/example/balance](https://github.com/Jorropo/web3/tree/fixing-2089/example/balance). But with the docs I'm not understanding how I precise javascript 1.7, no library, except mine finded [here](https://github.com/Jorropo/web3/blob/df1f896a135883aa7e66f8b36ba477194c12f4e5/example/balance/balance.details#L5), and how put github tree.